# PointCloudLibrary (PCL) - Octree - get indices of all points within a *branch* node

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I am new to PCL and I would like to get all indices from a **branch** node in `pcl::octree`. 
So, the root node for instance should provide every single index and each sub-branch node the indices of the points of all leaf nodes within this branch node. 
What is the best way of achieving this?

I am using a

```
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudSearch<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices, pcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices>
```

and hoped with the 3rd template parameter for the `BranchContainerT` also set to `pcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices` to be able to call something like

```
std::vector<int> indices;
auto it = m_octree->breadth_begin();
it.getBranchContainer().getPointIndices(indices)
```

However, the indices vector is empty. 
Of course, I can manually iterate over all the nodes, get the leafs and insert the indices, but maybe I am missing something here .. ?

Comment: Hmm, nobody familiar with PCL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I was missing is that the template parameter for `BranchContainerT` set to `pcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices` only *provides* you the option to store the indices in this kind of container. **However** adding these indices is something you have to do *manually*.

Given that it is just a matter of checking each node for its type and collect the indices from the leafs and add them to the branch nodes.